# Spring boot crash on hibernate validate, but database is wrong

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I got an error while work on project build with Spring Boot.

I use **hibernate** property to create the table:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

and application works fine. It also works if i use **update** value, but not **validate**! With validate it crashes with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframewor
k/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of
 init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missi
ng column: experience in greenwic_staging_id_it.job_chron_stg
```

When I look at this error message it becomes even more strange. The database name **greenwic_staging_id_it** is wrong. This database was used last year on this project. More over I work on local workstation with

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/indeeddb
```

When I run app it writes to my current indeeddb but not to old one. Where project could get this property value? I tried text search with "greenwic_staging_id_it" in project folder but nothing found there.

I tried maven clean, Eclipse-project-clean but no luck. Even if I build with maven and run jar in command line I get same wrong db. How to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Looks like this is the hibernate problem (not maven or spring). I found the database with old name still exist on my server. Once I delete it validation start work as it should. Here the description of same problem https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1027459&p=2491561#p2491561 . But how should I solve this, especially if I have few databases with same table names on production? Is the validation disable just one solution here?

**UPDATE**

POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>healthjobs</groupId>
    <artifactId>scraper</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HealthJobsScraper</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version> can safely omit -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>

            <!--
            <version>9.4.1208</version>
            <version>9.4.1207.jre7</version> 
             -->

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
         -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Maybe you are using some beans from dependencies, that are defining those old tables? It is indeed a weird error, indeederror!

Comment: I not see how this could happen. The pom pretty straightforward. It uses widely known library dependencies. The application not very large and I not define beans that use classes or configs from other projects. I will update initial message with pom file

Comment: Do you mean different schemas on the same database? With same tables? e.g. `schema1.tableX` & `schema2.tableX`?

Comment: I mean in MySQL two schemas with same table names. For me it looks like mySQL "schema" is the same as other people call "database"